# Error in installing python package Flair, about a dependent package not hosted in PyPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, flair

I am trying to install `flair`. It is throwing below error when executing below command:

`pip install flair`

`ERROR: Packages installed from PyPI cannot depend on packages which are not also hosted on PyPI.

tiny-tokenizer depends on SudachiDict_core@ https://object-storage.tyo2.conoha.io/v1/nc_2520839e1f9641b08211a5c85243124a/sudachi/SudachiDict_core-20190927.tar.gz`

I thought installing this package explicitly might fix the error but it doesn't. The error remains same. 
The installed version of SudachiDict-core is below:
`SudachiDict-core   0.0.0`

**Below is the Environment:**

- OS: Windows 10
- Python: 3.6 (64 bit)

Any hint is appreciated. Thank you!

Note:

- First hurdle when installing flair was `torch` package. It was resolved simply when torch package is installed. The error looked like below:
  `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.1.0 (from flair) (from verERROR: No matching distribution found for torch>=1.1.0 (from flair)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange running below command solved the problem.

`pip install flair==0.4.3`

I assume that the problem is in a latest version 0.4.4 (and its dependencies).

Note: I had `torch==1.1.0` package already installed.

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/zalandoresearch/flair.git
```

Source: https://github.com/flairNLP/flair/issues/1327#issuecomment-571639994

Or

to install separately:

```
pip install tiny-tokenizer
```

After this run:

```
pip install flair
```

Comment: Perhaps the command based on the latest flair repository should be:
`pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/flairNLP/flair.git`