# Packages installed from PyPI cannot depend on packages which are not also hosted on PyPI

Tags: python, pip

I want to install the package `cc_net`, however when I do `pip3 install cc_net` as shown [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/LASER/tree/main/tasks/CCMatrix#download) I get the following error:

```
Packages installed from PyPI cannot depend on packages which are not also hosted on PyPI.
cc_net depends on kenlm@ git+https://github.com/kpu/kenlm.git@master
```

What does this mean?

Comment: u can find an answer for that here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59559294/error-in-installing-python-package-flair-about-a-dependent-package-not-hosted-i

Comment: https://discuss.python.org/t/packages-installed-from-pypi-cannot-depend-on-packages-which-are-not-also-hosted-on-pypi/3736/6

Comment: What this means is quite obvious. The ways to solve it are less obvious. My advice is to avoid PyPI completely and install entirely from GitHub: `pip3 install git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/cc_net.git`